# Passing String argument from c to java using jni

Tags: java-native-interface

I am trying to call java method from C, but getting below error

> Status after JNI_CreateJavaVM=<0>
>   restCall method found:: Avinash Kumar
>
> Execution error : file ''
>   error code: 114, pc=0, call=1, seg=0
>   114     Attempt to access item beyond bounds of memory (Signal 11)

Target is to send String as an argument from C to Java function.

Below is the code :

```cpp
#include <jni.h>

#define ENV (*env)

enum eConst
{
   MAX_Options     =  21   ,
   MAX_LREF        = 120  ,
   PARSING_ERROR   = -10  ,
   ERROR           = -999 ,
   EXCEPTION_ERROR = -100 ,
   OK              = 1    ,
   YES             = 'Y'  ,
   NO              = 'N'
};

int main()
{
    jint    jRet;
    jstring   jszRes;
    static JavaVM *jvm = NULL;
    static JNIEnv *env  = NULL ;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[MAX_Options-1];
    int optionCount=0;
    options[optionCount++].optionString = "-verbose:jni,class,gc";
    char *path="user/work/avikumar/";
    char *class_path="user/work/avikumar/";
    char path_option[2000]={'\n'};
    sprintf(path_option,"-Djava.class.path=%s/MyClass.class:%s/jersey-core-1.19.jar:%s/jersey-client-1.19.jar:%s/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m02.jar:.",class_path,path,path,path);

    options[optionCount++].optionString = path_option;
    options[optionCount++].optionString = "-Xms128m";
    options[optionCount++].optionString = "-Xmx512m";
    options[optionCount++].optionString = "-Xss8m";

    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = optionCount;
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    jRet = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void**)&env,(void*)&vm_args);
    printf("Status after JNI_CreateJavaVM=<%d>\n",jRet);
    if (jRet < 0)
    {
       return(-4);
    }

    if( ENV->EnsureLocalCapacity(env, MAX_LREF) < 0)
    {
      printf( "\n out of memory. Program terminated\n");
      (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
      return(-5);
    }

    jclass jlocClass;
    jlocClass= ENV->FindClass(env, "MyClass");
    if (jlocClass == NULL || (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env))
    {
       printf("Can not load the main class\n");
       return (-6);
    }

    jmethodID restCall_method;
    restCall_method = ENV->GetMethodID(env, jlocClass,"restCall","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if( restCall_method == NULL)
    {
      printf("restCall method not found\n");
      return (-7);
    }

    char *inp =  "Avinash Kumar";
    printf("restCall method found:: %s\n",inp);
    //jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,inp);

    jstring jstr1=(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Avinash Kumar");

    ENV->CallVoidMethod(env, jlocClass, restCall_method,jstr1);
    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
    return 0;
}
```

MyClass.java

```java
class MyClass
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    System.out.println("Hello Avinash\n");
   }

   public void restCall(String inp)
   {
    System.out.println(inp+ " :: Hello Avinash from restCall\n");
   }

}
```

Comment: `restCall` is a non-static method. You are trying to call it by passing `jlocClass` as the receiver. Either make the method static (and use `CallStaticVoidMethod`) or create an instance of `MyClass` and pass that as receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix static/non-static context inside JNI. You have two choices.

**Static method**

```
restCall_method = ENV->GetStaticMethodID(
  env, jlocClass, "restCall", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
...
...
...
ENV->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, jlocClass, restCall_method,jstr1);
```

and, inside Java

```
public static void restCall(String inp)
```

or **non-static method**

```
jmethodID init = ENV->GetMethodID(env,jlocClass, "<init>", "()V");
jobject obj_MyClass = ENV->NewObject(env,jlocClass, init);

jmethodID restCall_method;
restCall_method = ENV->GetMethodID(env, jlocClass,"restCall","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
...
...
...
ENV->CallVoidMethod(env, obj_MyClass, restCall_method,jstr1);
```

and, inside Java

```
public void restCall(String inp)
```

In first case, you have to use ***Static*** family methods to get id and call target method, in second case, you have to create instance of class and use methods for object based context.